# Execute .NET 3.0 code from Office 2003

Tags: c#, .net, vba, ms-access, dll

I've created a DLL in C# using the .NET 3.0 framework.

Below is the code of my DLL

```
namespace CompanyName.Net
{
    [Guid("F7075E8D-A6BD-4590-A3B5-7728C94E372F")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("CompanyName.Net.Webrequest")]
    public class WebRequest
    {
        public string Result { get; private set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string StatusDescription { get; private set; }
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

        public WebRequest()
        {
            //explicit constructor
        }    

        public string GetResponse(string url)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest webreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) webreq.GetResponse();
            // Store the status.
            StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            Result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            //return the response
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this code to run from Office 2003 VBA code. The DLL was signed using the default Visual Studio 2008 signing.

I've managed to reference my assembly by creating a .TLB file using

```
regasm /tlb c:\CompanyName.Net.dll
```

But when I want to create an instance of the object:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim o As Object
    Set o = CreateObject("CompanyName.Net.WebRequest")
    Dim s As String
    s = o.GetResponse("http://www.google.be")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

> ActiveX component can't create Object

What am I doing wrong?

The machine I'm testing with has .NET installed up to the .NET 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, after some pretty good ideas from Thorsten Dittmar I finally got this thing to work.
Some things that came up during our discussion and other things I found on the web:

1. The .NET framework needs to be installed on the target machine.
2. .Net Programmability support needs to be installed on the target machine.
3. In AssemblyInfo.cs make sure you set

   > [assembly: ComVisible(**true**)]
4. As Thorsten pointed out you need to have parameterless public constructor in your .Net class.
5. Make sure to check "Register for COM Interop" in the Build tab on the Properties page of your project.
6. Make sure to sign your project using the Signing tab on the Properties page of your project.
7. Register your DLL on the target machine by running this command. The **/codebase** parameter seemed to do the trick for me. The path to the type library (.tlb) or DLL doesn't matter. You can find regasm at C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.050727\RegAsm.exe

   > regasm c:\CompanyName.Net.dll /tlb:CompanyName.Net.tlb **/codebase**
8. Reference the .tlb file in your VBA Editor using Tools > References.
9. Drag the dll from C:\ to your GAC at C:\Windows\assembly\ *(I didn't realize this at first but apparently it is necessary for Office to find your assembly.)*

That should do the trick.

I also upgraded my Webrequest class by adding an interface for it thus enabled [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) support in VB6 (which sadly enough does not work in VBA).

Comment: This is the most succinct and and only complete guide on this problem I found after hours of trying to get this to work. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You need an explicit parameterless constructor in your COM class. Change your class definition to:

```
namespace CompanyName.Net
{
    [Guid("F7075E8D-A6BD-4590-A3B5-7728C94E372F")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("CompanyName.Net.Webrequest")]
    public class WebRequest
    {
        public string Result { get; private set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string StatusDescription { get; private set; }
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

        public WebRequest()
        {
        }

        public string GetResponse(string url)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest webreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) webreq.GetResponse();
            // Store the status.
            StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            Result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            //return the response
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I just tried it but it still gives me the same error. I marked my project as "register for COM Interop" but no joy. Maybe the way I am calling my function in VBA is wrong? I am at a loss

Comment: I recreated the tlb file which should also reregister the dll. I can try adding it to the GAC again?

Comment: Also, it might help to wrap some code in GetResponse into try/catch blocks and handle the errors differently (don't know whether exceptions are handled gracefully from VBA code). When I have to do something like that I go back to returning an integer that indicates success or failure and setting a "ref" parameter to the error message.

Comment: No need to have it in the GAC - actually, I'd remove the GAC entry while testing. Maybe the new version isn't even being used thanks to the GAC entry?

Comment: Could be! just removed it. I should also mention maybe that I can only reference the .TLB and not the .DLL When I reference the DLL it tells me "Can't add a reference to the specified file".

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing. When I reference the .tlb file it references CompanyName_Net. But if I reference the dll itself it just tells me "Can't add reference to the specified file". Dunno if this causes the error I am getting.

Comment: Hm, then I'm at the end of what I know about COM interop with .NET. Two more things come to my mind: 1) re-add to the GAC, maybe that helps, 2) when writing office add-ins with .NET you need to make sure that .NET support is installed in Office - maybe that's the problem? Otherwise I can't help any further at this point.